# Visual Studio Find in Files search for exact string inside other strings

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, find

I need a help to find in files in Visual studio project a string which is contained in other two strings, that can be in different lines. These strings can contain any kind of special characters like <, / or " (for example tags).
For example I have

```
<div ID="d5">
  Hello world
</div>
```

I want to find all files (line number) where string `world` appears between `<div` (I don't care what is in tag attributes) and `</div>`

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex find

```
<div[^>]*>[^<]*?world[\s\S\n\r]*?</div>
```

`world` has to be before any other tag, it is not important what is after `world`.

---

If you give an example of your `CompareValidator` case we can be more specific.

Anything more complex requires a parsing of the file and an walk over the constructed Tree. You can do this with python or with node and an xpath search.

---

**Edit**

The solution by wasuregusa can be modified for VSC.

Because VSC does not have the Multi line option you have to simulate it with `[\s\S\n\r]`

```
<div((?!<div)[\s\S\n\r])*?world[\s\S\n\r]*?</div>
```

This will find more cases where there are non-div tags before the `world` string

Comment: So, if I understood you correctly, there is no 'universal' sloution for this problem? Like I set regular expression with boundaries strings and search text and it will find me whereever search string is found inside boundaries? I mean obviously my intention was not to find 'world' inside <div>, but I thought it is not worth to ask for my specific case. That is why I find this question worth my bounty. Because today I am searching for one thing and tomorrow for another. What I actually wanted to find is text "datepicker" inside <dec:DustTemplate ID="", OtherAttribute=""> and </dec:DustTemplate>

Comment: @ingbabic There are probably more cases of `<dec:DustTemplate ID="", OtherAttribute="">` before `datepicker`, but you want only the closes one with no other tag inbetween, you have write regex code that catches the stuff in-between the parts you want and that can contain newlines.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that a VS Code regular expression doesn't support recursion and so can't handle nested `<div>`s perfectly since it can't count the nesting level.

Aside from this limitation, here is the best I could come up with:

`<div(>|[\s\n]*[^>]*>)((.|\n)(?!<\/div[\s\n]*>)(?!<div(>|[\s\n]*[^>]*>)))*world((.|\n)(?!<\/div[\s\n]*>))*.?<\/div[\s\n]*>`

The above handles the possibility of whitespace and new lines within the `div` tags (which is valid HTML) and attempts to only match the innermost `<div>` where possible - but it will cut off short if the matched word is not within the innermost `<div>`, as shown in [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/6KnglM/1).

Comment: This works better. I tried to apply this solution to my case, but it doesn't work. What is wrong here?

<dec:DustTemplate(>|[\s\n]*[^>]*>)((.|\n)(?!<\/dec:DustTemplate[\s\n]*>)(?!<dec:DustTemplate(>|[\s\n]*[^>]*>)))*datepicker((.|\n)(?!<\/dec:DustTemplate[\s\n]*>))*.?<\/dec:DustTemplate[\s\n]*>

Comment: I thought that this is not that hard, honestly I was hoping for some magic regular expression where I could put my boundaries and search term and it will magicaly work. It looks like regular expressions simply can't make that. There are some remote possibilities, but each search is another story and you need to scratch your head over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do regex search across all files within vscode. But you could just use the pcregrep command.

```
$ cd your/project/dir 
$ pcregrep -Mrn <div((?!<div).)*?world.*?<\/div> .
```

- -M multiline
- -r recursive
- -n makes print line number of match
- .*? makes * lazy forces it find shortest match
- (?!<div) negative lookahead (otherwise first <div would get matched with first  after world)

Comment: Hmm, Visual Studio offers search by regular expression. It's a third option in Find in Files dialog

Comment: Good point. Then try putting that regex string in there. <div((?!<div).)*?world.*?<\/div>

Comment: in VSC `/` does not need to be escaped, most likely also not if used for `pcregrep`. For `pcregrep` you need to put the regex in `"` because you use `*` and `?`

Comment: @wasuregusa interesting, it did not found above example, but it did found this:
<div id="template2" class="ng-cloak">{{ 'world' }}</div>
Interesting enough this is in commented part of the code. Above sample div was in code not commented. However if I comment out my div it still does not show...